# Is $\{ \psi\in L^\infty(\sigma) \mid \operatorname{ess\,inf} \vert\psi\vert >0 \}$ meagre/nonmeagre/comeagre?

Tags: general-topology, lp-spaces

Let $\sigma\subset[0,1]$ be a measurable set with positive Lebesgue-measure. The set
$$
\{ \psi\in L^\infty(\sigma) \mid \operatorname{ess inf} \vert\psi\vert >0 \}
$$
is dense in $L^2(\sigma)$, but is it meagre/nonmeagre/comeagre?

> My problem is that I do not really understand these concepts and I
> can't find any good source which applies these terms to the $L^p$
> rooms. Can you give me some hints where to finde the answer or
> literature which adress this problem?

The motivation behind this question is that one can identify each possible frame $(T^n f)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ (for a given operator $T$) in a Hilbert space with a specific $\psi$ from the upper set. Actually I want to analyse the set of $f$'s in that Hilbert space that form a frame. I think that the $L^p$ spaces are analysed quite well so that it would be easier to analyse the upper set.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: $\{ \psi\in L^\infty(\sigma) \mid \operatorname{ess inf} \vert\psi\vert >0 \}$ is the union of the sets $\{ \psi\in L^\infty(\sigma) \mid \operatorname{ess inf} \vert\psi\vert \geq \frac 1  n\}$ each of which is closed with no interior.

Comment: @geetha290km Why is the second set closed? Say $\phi\in L^2(\sigma)\setminus L^\infty(\sigma)$ with $\operatorname{ess inf}\vert\phi\vert >0$, then there should be a sequence $\psi_n$ of step functions with $\psi_n\in L^\infty(\sigma)$, $\operatorname{ess inf} \vert\psi_n\vert >0$ and $\Vert \phi - \psi_n \Vert_{L^2} \to 0$.

I have the feeling that I get something wrong with the $L^p$ spaces but do not understand what.